# Cross-Saving possible?

Tags: python, django, model, save

Is there's a "cross-saving"-possibility between to models inside my django-application?

For example:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharfFeld()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    value_person= models.IntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateField
    

class Account():
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.Textarea()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value_a = models.IntegerField()
    value_b = models.IntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateField
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UpdateAccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        exclude = [
            'name',
            'date_created',
        ]
```

**views.py:**

```
[...]
    account_db = Account.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = UpdateAccountForm(instance=Account)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST, instance=Account)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            *** Do something here
            return("Somehwere")
[...]
```

Now I'm asking myself, if it's possible - while updating the "Account" - to update the "Person" and - let's say for example - add one of the two "values_..." into the "value_person"? The connection should be there via the "ForeignKey", right? I think I should also mention, that I'm talking about my default database!
I'm aware that this might be a bad example, but it's just so that I can understand the system behind this - hopefully existing - function!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to update the person linked to the account by querying the Person object in the db that matches the foreign key value in the Account object and then updating that Person object with whatever values you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can do this with the code below. However, as far as I know, there is no function that does this. [foreign key relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships)

```
account_instance = Account.object.get(id=1)
person = account_instance.person
person.value_person += 1 
person.save()
```

For example, if you want it only in view, you can do as in the code below

```
[...]
account_db = Account.objects.get(id=pk)

form = UpdateAccountForm(instance=Account)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST, instance=Account)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        person = account_db.person
        person.value_person += 1 
        person.save()
        return("Somehwere")
[...]
```

Or if you want this logic to be executed every time when model is saved, you can do with the overriding the save method of the Account class. [overriding model save](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-the-save-method-django-models/#:%7E:text=The%20save%20method%20is%20an,save()%20function%20is%20run.)

```
class Account():
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.Textarea()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value_a = models.IntegerField()
    value_b = models.IntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateField 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.person.value_person += 1 
        self.person.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # don't forget to call super method
```

Also, I don't recommend it but you can use the post save signal. As a note, it is difficult to debug signals.[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Account)
def increase_person_values(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.person.value_person += 1
    instance.person.save()
```

Comment: What a great solution and explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: If I may ask: Is this also possible with a complete new entry in a model without any connections via a Foreign Key?

Comment: If there is no connection between models, there is no shortcut either, but you can always perform similar operations by using ORM.